# Porque não consigo criar uma tablespace?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g

Estou tentando criar uma tablespace no oracle 11g porém não consigo ele aponta o erro que esta nessa imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria entender o porque não consigo criar!

Answer (score -1):

Romulo,

Não tenho como simular teu erro porque pode ser algo da tua infra, mas trabalhei um tempo banco de dados Oracle e com as pesquisas que fiz encontrei um artigo que se aproxima muito do que você está passando.

Dá uma olhada lá: https://dbaland.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/ora-19502-write-error-on-file/

No caso do artigo era falta de espaço em disco, devemos levar em consideração que o sistema operacional pode estar configurado para alocar espaço em disco para auxiliar a memória RAM, é a memória virtual e dependendo de onde você olha esse espaço que está alocado não é mostrado como "indisponivel".

Creio que não seja isso porque está tentando criar uma tablespace de 1GB que é até bem pequena, mas é o que consigo tentar lhe ajudar com a informação que tenho.

Não sei se está usando mas tente executar o sqlplus com o prompt em modo 'Administrador" e utilizar os usuários sys ou system conectando como sysdba.

Até mais!

Comment: Sim, amigo a principio era isso mesmo! Porém ele deu outro erro só que desta vez na hora de executar o assistente que eu estou utilizando (Swingbench). Estou dando uma procura na internet para ver se consigo resolver isso! MUITO OBRIGADO já me ajudou muito!